# JSON formatting by appending dict values to list

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON object which is like this:

```
{ "produktNr:"1234",
  "artNr_01":"12",
  "artNr_02":"23",
  "artNr_03":"",
  "artNr_04":"14",
  "name_01":"abc",
  "name_02":"der",
  "test":"junk"
}
```

I would like to convert this into a dictionary like this:

```
{ "produktNr:"1234", "artNr":["12","23","","14"], "name":["abc","der"], "test":"junk"}
```

This conversion is based on a sequence given say, `seq = ["artNr","name"]`. So the contents of the sequence are searched in the dictionary's keys and the values collected into a list.

My attempt so far:

```
tempDict = {}
for key,value in fmData.iteritems():
    for seqval in seq:
        if seqval in key:
            if seqval in tempDict:
                tempDict[seqval].append(value)
            else:
                x = []
                x.append(value)
                tempDict[seqval]=x
        else:
            tempDict[key] = value
```

faces a few problems.

- The list of values are not ordered i.e, `"artNr":["","14","12","23"]`
  instead of values of `[_01,_02,_03,_04]`
- The items cannot be popped from the dictionary since in the loop the dictionary items cannot be deleted resulting in:

  { "produktNr:"1234", "artNr":["12","23","","14"],"artNr_01":"12", "artNr_02":"23",     "artNr_03":"","artNr_04":"14","name":["abc","der"],"name_01":"abc", "name_02":"der", "test":"junk"}

Would love to understand how to deal with this, especially if there's a pythonic way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `OrderedDict` from the `collections` package:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import re

input_dict = { "produktNr":"1234",
               "artNr_01":"12",
               "artNr_02":"23",
               "artNr_03":"",
               "artNr_04":"14",
               "name_01":"abc",
               "name_02":"der",
               "test":"junk" }

# split keys on the first '_'
m = re.compile('^([^_]*)_(.*)')

def _order_by( item ):
    # helper function for ordering the dict.
    # item is split on first '_' and, if it was successful 
    # the second part is returned otherwise item is returned
    # if key is something like artNr_42, return 42
    # if key is something like test, return test 
    k,s = item
    try:
        return m.search(k).group(2)
    except:
        return k

# create ordered dict using helper function
orderedDict = OrderedDict( sorted(input_dict.items(), key=_order_by))

aggregated_dict = {}
for k, v in orderedDict.iteritems():
    # split key
    match = m.search(k)

    if match:
        # key is splittable, i.e., key is something like artNr_42
        kk = match.group(1)
        if kk not in aggregated_dict:
            # create list and add value
            aggregated_dict[kk] = [v]
        else:
            # add value
            aggregated_dict[kk].append(v)
    else:
        # key is not splittable, i.e., key is something like produktNr
        aggregated_dict[k] = v

print(aggregated_dict)
```

which gives the desired output

```
{'produktNr': '1234', 'test': 'junk', 'name': ['abc', 'der'], 'artNr': ['12', '23', '', '14']}
```

Comment: This is absolutely beautiful @desiato.. Thanks a lot. I learnt a lot from that piece of code actually: using sorted with keys, using re.search and compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate a new dictionary that will group values of keys with `'_'` in the keys in a list while the other keys and values are kept intact. This should do:

```
d = { "produktNr":"1234", "artNr_01":"12", "artNr_02":"23","artNr_03":"","artNr_04":"14","name_01":"abc","name_02":"der","test":"junk"}
new_d= {}
for k, v in d.items():
    k_new = k.split('_')[0]
    if '_' in k:
        if k_new not in new_d:
            new_d[k_new] = [v]
        else:
            new_d[k_new].append(v)
    else:
        new_d[k_new] = v
print(new_d)
# {'artNr': ['', '14', '23', '12'], 'test': 'junk', 'produktNr': '1234', 'name': ['der', 'abc']}
```

Dicts are `unordered` collections, so the order with which the values are appended to the list will be indeterminate.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Moses.. Is it possible somehow to have it ordered?

Comment: If you use an `OrderedDict` for both dictionaries. If the order has a pattern, you may consider sorting with `sorted`

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification of your code:

```
tempDict = {}
for key,value in fmData.iteritems():
    seqval_in_key = "no"
    for seqval in seq:
        if seqval in key:
            seqval_in_key = "yes"
    for seqval in seq:
        if seqval in key:
            if seqval in tempDict:
                tempDict[seqval].append(value)
            else:
                x = []
                x.append(value)
                tempDict[seqval]=x
        else:
            if (seqval_in_key == "no"):
                tempDict[key] = value
print tempDict
```

Result:

```
{'produktNr': '1234', 'test': 'junk', 'name': ['abc', 'der'], 'artNr': ['14', '23', '', '12']}
```